# User has to login on every page of MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a MVC 5 application for the first time. I have implemented a individual User Accounts authentication setup. This works fine when I am working on my local machine in Visual Studio 2015. But when I publish the project to a webserver I get the following annoying issue. Users can log in - no problems. They can go to another page, sometimes this gives no problems sometimes the user is redirected to the login page and has to login again. The user can login and no further problems arise on that page. But when the user goes to another page sometimes this gives no problems and sometimes the user is redirectes again to the login again.

I suspect there is some issue with the webserver (IIS) but I have examined every possible setting, but cannot find anything suspicious. Any suggestions/help on this would be appriciated.

Comment: Is this forms authentication, check the cookie settings, or create cookie settings in code. If it is windows authentication, check if it works fine in IE.

Comment: Could you us web.config *(please mask sensitive information)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem you're facing, but still i would suggest to check your session timeout in Web.config file.

Try increasing it if it is too low.

Look for the sessionState tag in the config file.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="9999" />
```

Comment: Thanks Shahbaz!,

This did do the trick. I had not noticed the session state parameter was not copied to webserver in webconfig.

Thanks!!